# Android: How to cover the whole layout by a view programatically while the layout contains buttons already?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, view, android-linearlayout

I've a linear layout filled by buttons(view1 - view5).

I would like to add a view(red star) to this layout and I want this red star to cover the whole layout and its buttons (without setting the visibility of them)

**in the attached image:**

1 - the layout I've, filled by buttons

2- the layout I want to achieve by adding my red star programmatically

How can I do so?[image]

Comment: When you say __without setting the visibility of them__, does that include the star? Because you could easily put the star in the XML as `invisible` and then set it to `visible`. Otherwise, it is still possible. You have to instanciate the `View` with the star and build it to the attributes you want, and then add it to your layout, probably inside your root `ViewGroup` (`RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First switch the root layout to a RelativeLayout, something like

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <View android:id="@+id/view1"
          ... />
    <View android:id="@+id/view2"
          ... 
          android:layout_below="@id/view1" />
    <View android:id="@+id/view3"
          ...
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/view2"
          android:layout_below="@id/view1" />
    ...
```

Then at the bottom of that layout add your overlay which ignores all the other views (so can draw over them)

```
    <View android:id="@+id/overlay"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```